# text area in html jumps on focus

Tags: jquery, css, html

i have a html tag for text area as below...

```
<div>
    <span class="l" style="padding-top: 77px">
        <textarea id="txt7" rows="3" cols="50">Lorem ipsum</textarea>
    </span>
</div>
```

on focus i am changing border color and border width it worked fine.
the problem when i do focus on that element text area box jumps on the page (means moves a little bit....)

css:

```
textarea:focus { .br; border-style: solid; .shdw; }
```

so any work around to this plz.............

how abt using box-shawdow property .....i am not aware of using it ........so do any help there on this............

Comment: The border could make it jump because a 1px border all around adds 1px on all sides of the textarea. Take a look at `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Comment: .br .shdw - what are those things?

Comment: `textarea` inside `span`... can you move out of span?

Comment: those holds border -width etc.,

Comment: I don't understand your CSS rule, what are .br and .shdw doing in there? are these classes?  You can't put a class within a class...

Answer (score 1):

That's because the border thickness is not accounted for when there is no border and doesn't anticipate a changing border (naturally).

Try setting a fixed border size in the CSS for when the *element is not in focus*, and for this to be transparent (or effectively transparent (i.e. matching background colour)), then on focus all you need to change for the border is the colour.

Answer (score 1):

Throw that in your css and it will stay where it is supposed to. 
    - Hope this helps.

```
#txt7{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check [This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cxquE/).

I dint find any problem.
1 reason might be that the css is conflicting with another css defined for

```
<div> or <span> or <textarea>
```

Try to find out if there is any conflicting css.