# Text area behaviour on first focus

Tags: html, symfony

On the first time rendering of my web page, and then focussing in text area section, the text area space jumps out of the frame. The behavior is different for different browsers, as you can see in screenshots:

**Actual presentation**
[image: Actual presentation]

**On Chrome**
[image: On Chrome]

**On firefox**
[image: On firefox]

This thing is happening only when the focus is made for the first time after page render. I found one of this sort of similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475010/text-area-in-html-jumps-on-focus) but unable to get an answer there, as it happens only one time so there should not be CSS conflicts in my code.

Comment: Post your css please. pretty hard to help you otherwise

Comment: try something like this: `input[type="text"]:focus,textarea:focus{
    border: 1px solid #03a9f4;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}`

Comment: looks like the white background is moving, please post a code example so we can debug

Comment: Yeah it looks like you are using a separate div as the background instead of setting the background of the text area to white

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found one thing while looking for CSS as @Joel asked for it, as the application is being built under Symfony and being rendered with its concept only, Symfony applying some CSS onto it on the first focus.

The text area created by me has width related CSS only, and is being prepared as:

```
<textarea id="create_article_content" name="create_article[content]" class="tinymce"></textarea>
```

On focus it is getting converted to:

```
<textarea id="create_article_content" name="create_article[content]" class="tinymce" data-gramm="true" data-gramm_editor="true" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important; z-index: auto; position: relative; line-height: 24px; font-size: 16px; transition: none 0s ease 0s;"></textarea>
```

Basically, it adds `position: relative` which causes this effect and to avoid this behavior I needed to write

`textarea:focus {
        position: sticky!important;
    }`

I am not sure if this should be the correct answer though.